# Loop through a file and display each line in a tkinter window after previous window has been closed?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-2.x

There are lines in a text file that i want to show in a Tkinter window. After the line is shown, the Tkinter window disappears, comes back again and displays the next line in the file, the windows disappears and repeats the process again until the script is stopped.

So far the script I wrote displays all the lines in the file at the same time, disappears and appears again, repeats the same process, until the script is stopped.Here is the code:

```
import Tkinter as Tk
import time

class Window:
   def __init__(self):
       self.root = None
       self.hide = 10 #minutes
      self.show = 10 #seconds

   def close(self):
       self.root.destroy()
       return

   def new(self):
      fh=open('subliminal.txt')
      lines = fh.read().splitlines()
      self.root = Tk.Tk()
      for line in lines:
         Tk.Button(self.root, text= line, command='callback').pack()
         self.root.after(self.show*1000, self.loop)

   def loop(self):
      if self.root:
           self.root.destroy()
      time.sleep(self.hide)
      self.new()
      self.root.mainloop()
      return

Window().loop()
```

This script is written in Python 2 but I am also open to doing this in another GUI since it is light-weight.

Thanks,this worked for me:

```
import Tkinter as Tk
import time

class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.hide = 10 #minutes
        self.show = 10 #seconds

    def close(self):
        self.root.destroy()
        return

    def new(self):
        fh=open('subliminal.txt')
        lines = fh.read().splitlines()
        for line in lines:
           self.root = Tk.Tk()
           Tk.Button(self.root, text= line,    command='callback').pack()
           self.root.update()
           time.sleep(5)

           self.root.destroy()

     def loop(self):

         self.new()
         self.root.mainloop()
         self.loop()
         return

Window().loop()
```

Comment: am also open to doing this in python3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this may be what you are looking for:

```
import tkinter as Tk
import time

class Window:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.hide = 10 #minutes
        self.show = 10 #seconds

    def close(self):
        self.root.destroy()
        return

    def new(self):
        fh=open('subliminal.txt')
        lines = fh.read().splitlines()
        for line in lines:
            self.root = Tk.Tk()
            Tk.Button(self.root, text= line, command='callback').pack()
            self.root.update()
            time.sleep(5)
            #self.root.mainloop()
            self.root.destroy()

    def loop(self):
        #if self.root:
            #self.root.destroy()
        #time.sleep(self.hide)
        self.new()
        #self.root.mainloop()
        return

Window().loop()
```

When I run it, it makes a window for 5 seconds with the first line then a new window with the next line and so on. You may want to include a close check, because the exit button will not work due to the use of `update()` instead of `mainloop()`.

Comment: Pls how do I include a close check